# How do I find <a>-tags with the same href, so I can add classes to all elements with same <a>-tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two lists, one contains clickable text-links and the other one contains clickable images with the same links. Now I want to add a class to both elements containing the same -tag, so when I hover over one of them, both get affected.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated a lot!

```
$('a[href]').hover(function () {
  var $this = $( this );
  var $links = $( "a[href=' + $this.attr( 'href' ) + ']");
  $links.addClass("hover");
},
function(){
  $('a[href]').removeClass("hover");

});
```

Comment: Apart from a mismatch quote typo , your code isn't looking for any `<img>` elements It is looking for the same `<a>` that is already being hovered.

Comment: Please provide sample html as per  [mcve]

Comment: If you fix the quotes in `var $links = $( "a[href=' + $this.attr( 'href' ) + ']");`, your code will work.

Comment: I dont get what is wrong with the quotes, when I try other ways of quotes I get an error, I just don't get it.

Comment: I think I got it, S—O—R—R—Y!